# How to use a function inside a class' __init__ function

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

In Python 2.7 I have this class definition:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,ahg):
        self.ahg=ahg
        def oaf(arg):
            return arg*2
        self.tooAhg=self.oaf(self.ahg)
```

At console I make the following statements

```
>>> bibi=foo(1)
>>> vars(bibi)
{'ahg': 1}
```

I don't know why `vars(bibi)` does not return `{'ahg': 1, 'tooAhg': 2}`. Please help!  Furthermore,
another unsuccessful strategy is this:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,ahg):
        self.ahg=ahg
        self.tooAhg=self.oaf()
    def oaf(self):
        return self.ahg*2
```

Comment: Your second example works for me... Also, it's generally not always a good idea to put functions inside functions.

Comment: @Zizouz212 wrapping a function in another function is NOT uncommon - there are a few examples in the [functools module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and [decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) are pretty usefull.

Comment: @Zizouz212 -- I don't much like defining a function inside another function. But I see no reason not to call a function from another function.

Comment: Being able to define a function inside another is incredibly powerful.  Its why C++, C# and Java had to implement lambdas (Python has them, but they are not needed as often).  See also : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had read the error message from the first example then that might have given you a clue.

```
self.tooAhg=self.oaf(self.ahg)
AttributeError: foo instance has no attribute 'oaf'
```

The function name is `oaf`, not `self.oaf`.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,ahg):
        self.ahg=ahg
        def oaf(arg):
            return arg*2
        self.tooAhg=oaf(self.ahg)

bibi=foo(1)
print vars(bibi)
```

Gives:

```
{'tooAhg': 2, 'ahg': 1}
```

If you want to make the function `oaf` an attribute of the object, then:

```
self.oaf = oaf
```

Comment: Okay I accept this code. It fixes the bug in my program. Thank you.

Comment: @EricVonB: then could you please check my answer as the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fits your use-case but if `tooAhg` has to be `2*ahg` always, you should use properties:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, ahg):
        self.ahg = ahg

    @property
    def tooAhg(self):
        return 2 * self.ahg
```

Now, you can access `tooAhg` like any other class field (ex. `self.tooAhg`), without worrying about updating it whenever you update `ahg`